# How should Vue filters be bound using typescript?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

How should Vue filters be bound using TypeScript? It is fairly straightforward with pure js, but I'm running into issue converting it to TypeScript.

The code and compile error are as follows:

**app.ts**

```
import * as Vue from 'vue'
...
import * as filters from './util/filters'

// register global utility filters.
Object.keys(filters).forEach(key => {
  Vue.filter(key, filters[key]);
})
```

**util/filters.ts**

```
export function host (url: string) {
  ...
}

export function timeAgo (time: any) {
  ....
}
```

**Compile Error**

*error TS7017: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'typeof ...' has no index signature.*

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I'm using a library called [vue-property-decorator](https://github.com/kaorun343/vue-property-decorator) where you can do something like:

```
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator'

@Component({
  name: 'ComponentName',
  filters: {
    filterName(value: any) {
      return 'Hello filter'
    }
  }
})
export default class ComponentName extends Vue {
  textToFormat = 'Hello world'
}
```

Then to apply the filter:

```
<p>{{ textToFormat | filterName }}</p>
```

Happy coding!

Comment: So you manually inject and repeat your code in every component?

Comment: You could add filters you want to reuse as a global filter to the Vue instance, see [https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters). This is typcially done in the `main.js` file where you bootstrap your project.

Comment: Question was not regards on how to make it globally, it was about your code above with class-component style. Have you tried to include all your filters inside main.ts? I have faced types issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57672886/using-global-filters-in-vue-with-typescript

Comment: @AlexanderKim you can do as follows:

`import { myFilter } from '@/filters/my.filter';` and `@Component({ filters: { myFilter } })`

Comment: @Arajay, i mean global import in all components, not one by one.

Comment: How can I access this filter inside the class ComponentName?

Answer (score 3):

I register global filters like this:

Inside `plugins/filters.ts`:

```
import { VueConstructor } from 'vue/types/umd'

export default {
  install (Vue: VueConstructor) {
    Vue.filter('someFormatFunc1', function someFormatFunc1(value) {
      // Your formatting function
    })
    Vue.filter('someFormatFunc2', function someFormatFunc2(value) {
      // Your formatting function
    })
  }
}
```

Then inside `main.ts`:

```
import filters from './plugins/filters'
Vue.use(filters)
```

Answer (score 2):

For adding the filter globally, I did something as following

```
// in customFilter.ts file

import Vue from 'vue';

const testFilter = Vue.filter(
  'filterName', () => {
    // filter fn
   }
);
export default testFilter;
```

and include this in main.ts

```
import testFilter from '@/customFilter.ts'

new Vue({
...
  filters: {
    testFilter
  },
...
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me (Vue2 + TypeScript):

Define filters in filters.ts

```
export default ({
  filterName1(value: any) { return 'Hello filter 1' },
  filterName2(value: any) { return 'Hello filter 2' }
} as { [key: string]: any })
```

and then, register filters globally in main.ts

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import filters from '@/filters'

// register filters
Object.keys(filters).forEach(key => { Vue.filter(key, filters[key]) }) 

new Vue({store, render: h => h(App)}).$mount('#app')
```

Hope this could help

Answer (score -1):

In this case your can simple use Type Assertion

```
Object.keys(filters).forEach(key => {
  Vue.filter(key, (filters as any)[key])
})
```