# Using global filters in Vue with Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

Using `vue-property-decorator` with Vue 2.6.

main.ts file:

```
import filters from '@/filters/filters'
Object.keys(filters).forEach(key => Vue.filter(key, filters[key]))
```

filters.ts file:

```
import format from 'date-fns/format'

export default {
  unixDateToHuman: (date: number | Date, dateFormat: string) => {
    return format(date, 'dd.MM.yyyy - hh:mm:ss')
  }
}
```

However i'm getting type error in main.ts:

`Object.keys(filters).forEach(key => Vue.filter(key, filters[key]))`

It says:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ unixDateToHuman: (date: number | Date, dateFormat: string) => string; }'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ unixDateToHuman: (date: number | Date, dateFormat: string) => string; }'
```